# Luke-Lucene Index Tool for searching

Tags: lucene

I have a scenario to search. for that i am using Lucene Index Tool. so how can i make a query with less than or greater than conditions. presently it is taking only OR , AND.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the website http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_2_0/queryparsersyntax.html, luncene is not support less than or greater than conditions.
Maybe Range Searches will do it.

Comment: thanks. That what you said is right and i am using TO to get the effect of between